# Mesh generation for a discrete set of points in ListContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, mesh

Given a (possibly disjoint) region, defined by a discrete set of points, how can I use `ListContourPlot[]` together with `Mesh` to highlight a specific area of the plot? For instance, how can I mesh the region where the points are smaller than a certain value?

Here I construct a minimal example where I try to highlight the area where the values of a discrete sample of the function $f(x) = e^{x^2 - y^2}$ are smaller then one.

```
data = Table[Exp[x^2 - y^2], {x, -1, 1, .01}, {y, -1, 1, .01}];

ListContourPlot[
 data
 , Contours -> {1.0}
 , ContourStyle -> Transparent
 , Mesh -> 25
 , MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 &}
 , MeshStyle -> Thick
 ]
```

I also tried using `MeshFunctions -> {Piecewise[{{#1 + #2 &, #3 <= 1 &}, {None, #3 > 0 &}}]}`, but I had no luck.

I am aware that this can be done for symbolic functions through `RegionPlot[]`, however I am not sure how to extend this to numerical data.

[image: Mesh in ListContourPlot]

Comment: `MeshFunctions -> {( # + #2) Boole[#3 <= 1] &}`?

Comment: @kglr this works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: `data = Table[Exp[x^2 - y^2], {x, -1, 1, .01}, {y, -1, 1, .01}];

ListContourPlot[data, Contours -> {1.0}, ContourStyle -> Transparent, 
 Mesh -> 25, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, f}, If[f > 1, x + y, 0]], 
   Function[{x, y, f}, If[f < 1, x - y, 0]]}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Red, Directive[Thick, Green]}]`

Comment: @cvgmt this also works perfectly. Thank you everyone for the excellent replies!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data = Table[Exp[x^2 - y^2], {x, -1, 1, .01}, {y, -1, 1, .01}];

ListContourPlot[data, Contours -> {1.0}, ContourStyle -> Transparent, 
 ContourShading -> {Directive[Orange, HatchFilling[-Pi/4, 1, 10]], 
   Directive[Cyan, HatchFilling[Pi/4, 1, 8]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
data = Table[Exp[x^2 - y^2], {x, -1, 1, .01}, {y, -1, 1, .01}];

Show[
 ListContourPlot[data,
    Contours -> {1},
    Mesh -> 25,
    MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 &},
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, #[[1]]],
    RegionFunction -> #[[2]]] & /@
  {{Red, 
    Function[{x, y, f}, f < 1]},
   {Black, Function[{x, y, f}, f > 1]}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Excellent replies as usual by @cvgmt and @Bob Hanlon, but I'd like to give it a go using `Piecewise`

With

```
data = Table[Exp[x^2 - y^2], {x, -1, 1, .01}, {y, -1, 1, .01}];
```

The following works nicely I think

```
ListContourPlot[data,
 Contours -> {1.0},
 ContourStyle -> Transparent,
 Mesh -> 25,
 MeshFunctions -> {Piecewise[{{#1 + #2, #3 <= 1}}] &, 
   Piecewise[{{None, #1 + #2 >= 1}}] &},
 MeshStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: piecewise]